# Unity Physics2D.IgnoreCollision not functioning properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm attempting to get two objects to ignore each other. I tried to implement the Physics2D.IgnoreCollision code, but as it stands, the first object falls from the sky, and either A) directly hits the object below, stays there for a second, and then continues moving down the screen, or B) merely glances off the object below if it hits it from a side angle. I want the two to completely ignore each other.

Here is my code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "obj") {
        Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A (typically) better solution is to use layers to manage collision between categories of items. You would assign `obj`-tagged objects to a particular layer, and the object in your post to another layer, then go into the Unity Physics Manager to disable collision between those layers. Further direction on that is available in the [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html).

But if you must use tags, there is still a solution.

If you're calling `Physics2D.IgnoreCollision` inside of a collision event, then you are only ignoring their collision *after* the collision event has affected the velocity, etc. of the objects. So, basically you're calling it too late.

A better alternative to get the behavior you're looking for is to call it in a method that runs after both objects have been created. The challenge there, is that you need a way to get a reference to the other game object you want to ignore.

One solution is to put the call into the objects in their OnEnable() methods, and then use `FindGameObjectsWithTag` to find the other objects to ignore:

```
public class OneObject : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnEnable() {
        GameObject[] otherObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("obj");

        foreach (GameObject obj in otherObjects) {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(obj.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), GetComponent<Collider2D>()); 
        }

        // rest of OnEnable
    }
   // rest of class ...
}
```

If you put this in the `OnEnable` of both both types of objects (with the tag of the other object of course), it should meet your needs.

Comment: This worked great! I had to switch it from "Start" to "Update", but after that, everything went smoothly.

Comment: The best place for ignoreCollision imo is in the OnEnable. That's because they are "lost" when the object is disabled. Btw if you are to leave it in Update check the profiler to see if that affects performance more than you are ok with.

Comment: @Nikaas Great suggestion. I've edited my answer to suggest that.